# use a map() for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, array-map

how do I want to fill the undefined value in the seats array with the value in `namaPenumpang`

my code

I have tried using a `for` loop it worked

```
var kursi = [undefined, "galih"];

function tambahPenumpang(namaPenumpang, kursi) {
  // jika angkot masih kosong
  if (kursi.length == 0) {
    kursi.push(namaPenumpang);
    return kursi;
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < kursi.length; i++) {
      if (kursi[i] === undefined) {
        kursi[i] = namaPenumpang;
        return kursi;
      } else if (namaPenumpang === kursi[i]) {
        console.log("Kursi ini sudah terisi oleh " + kursi[i]);
        return kursi;
      } else if (kursi[i] !== undefined) {
        kursi.push(namaPenumpang);
        return kursi;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How my code work use a `map()`?

Please help me to solve this problem, how can the contents of the array at the index with the value unndefined be replaced using the value namaPenumpang

Comment: `map()` is used to create a new array, not to modify the existing array. Use `forEach()` to loop over an array just for side effects.

Comment: Also, you can't stop a `map()` in the middle. Your function returns as soon as it finds the first `undefined` element, this is not an appropriate use of `map()` or `forEach()`.

Comment: In fact, it always returns on the first iteration, because the last `else if` will always be true if the first `if` is false.

Comment: If you want to replace all undefined elements with `namaPenunmpang` then you shouldn't have `return kurssi` in all the `if` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

`map` always returns an array of the same size. So you cannot add new items.

The logic of your code probably does not do what you intend.

Here are some modifications:

```js
let arr = ["x", undefined, "z"];

function tambahPenumpang(namaPenumpang, kursi) {
  // it is confusing to modify the original array and return it
  // so we create a new array and leave the original array untouched
  const newArr = [...kursi];
  if (newArr.includes(namaPenumpang)) {
    console.log("Kursi ini sudah terisi oleh " + namaPenumpang);
    return newArr;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    if (newArr[i] === undefined) {
      newArr[i] = namaPenumpang;
      return newArr;
    }
  }
  // if we reach here, then it was not added
  newArr.push(namaPenumpang);
  return newArr;
}

arr = tambahPenumpang("x", arr); // Kursi ini sudah terisi oleh x
console.log(arr);                // ["x", undefined, "z"]
arr = tambahPenumpang("y", arr);
console.log(arr);                // ["x", "y", "z"]
arr = tambahPenumpang("a", arr);
console.log(arr);                // ["x", "y", "z", "a"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same functionality with the map function.

```
var kursi = [undefined, "galih"];
function tambahPenumpang(namaPenumpang, kursi) {
  kursi = kursi.map((penumpang) => {
    if (penumpang === undefined) {
      return namaPenumpang;
    } else {
      return penumpang;
    }
  });
  return kursi;
}
```